# Implement any loading indicator inside private framework without add dependencies

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, sdk

Hey i'm building an SDK that is a set of screens.
The host app suppose to init the SDK with some configurations, and the SDK is responsible for presenting the screens.
The SDK is both for iOS and Android.
On iOS i'm searching for the topViewController of the app and presenting the flow from there, and on android i'm opening a new Activity with the flow.

For customization i added a public UI configuration object that let the Host app change colors, fonts, icons and more.

The only part that is public to the host is the initialization, configuration and customization objects, the screens, UI elements and the business logic is internal for the SDK.

I tried to figure out a way to let the host app inject any loading indicator, to replace the default loading indicator.

Some hosts use Lottie, some use GIF, and more.
So i'm trying to prevent the SDK to depend on 3rd party pods\SDKs.

Some of my thoughts was:

1.Using public protocol that the host app will implement, to provide the SDK with the loading indicator view, each time the SDK needs it, but it doesn't look like a best practice idea.

2.Add a loading indicator view to the customization object, but i prefer not to hold the view the entire flow.

What is the best practice for that?

Comment: the host app can optionally provide a closure in the UIConfiguration object which creates the loading indicator view and you can just add the view to your view. if need arises.. If the view changes from screen to screen, you can implement a delegate based mechanism where you request back for a view on demand.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought, but on the android side the developer told me it is not a best practice. so i'm trying to think of other ways.